# See the raw IMAP commands when using imaplib or imap_tools

Tags: python, python-3.x, imaplib, imap-tools

I am writing a Python 3 script to handle IMAP mailboxes, and I am having some problems with the server. When I connect to it "by hand" and try to send raw IMAP commands, the server is unresponsive, and yet when I run the script it does what it does correctly.

Anyway, in order to find out what's happening with the server I need to see raw IMAP commands that my script is sending, and specially the server's responses. Is there any way to make either imaplib or imap_tools (the two libraries that I've tried) log that information?

Comment: By hand you usually need to tell your socket tool to send CRLFs when you press enter. For example with OpenSSL s_client this is the -crlf option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the debug attribute in the IMAP4 class to enable debug output, which includes responses.

As no logging is available in IMAP.